# Controlling that colums are filled in before closing a issue. Not red star

Tags: 2007, list

We have a issue tracking on accidents. Is pretty straight forward. Employees register an issue based on the colums with red star. The leader receives an email and do the research on accident. But we have experienced that certain colums doesn't get filled out before they(leaders) close the issue.

Is there a way to do this easy or by inserting script in a CEWB or so?
For example: **Status** colum will not accept "closed" before **Category** colum is filled out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Designer you could set up a custom workflow to run when an item is modified. If **Status**=Closed and **Category** is empty. Send email to leader telling them they haven't completed **Category** and update the list item's **Status** back to open.

Answer (score 0):

One options could be :
to Add custom list forms using infopath [see here](http://blog.libinuko.com/2010/03/21/sharepoint-2010-howto-start-customize-list-form-neweditview-using-infopath-designer-2010/)
And then is more easy to set rules. Replace the default edit form with a infopath form. Hope that help.